pyenv is killed during module installation?
I installed pyenv (on Debian 12) as I need to run a program that uses python 10.
Now I also need a module called local-attention.
So I tried to install it with pip:
pip install --user local-attention
Collecting local-attention
  Using cached local_attention-1.9.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting einops>=0.6.0
  Downloading einops-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
     |                             | 43 kB 370 kB/s 
Collecting torch
  Downloading torch-2.3.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (779.1 MB)
     |                              | 779.1 MB 18.2 MB/s eta 0:00:01/home/lucas/.pyenv/pyenv.d/exec/pip-rehash/pip: line 20:  3694 Killed                  "$PYENV_COMMAND_PATH" "$@"
 

But it looks like pip is killed during the process.
And if I check for the module installation:
python -c "import local_attention"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'local_attention'

Can someone help me ?

Any logs in /var/log/messages or /var/log?

please provide the output of pip --version

@Setop pip 21.2.3 from /home/lucas/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)

@Duddy67, it is a bit old :) There is a similar issue reported for version 22: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11429 ; can you upgrade to last version (24.x) and retry ? I can be done with pip install -U pip
